# How to fine-tune a JPA/JAX-RS application

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jax-rs, database-connection

I've developed a JAX-RS JSON API in Wildfly/RESTeasy with a JPA/Hibernate backend and I have serious database access problems.

For example, suddenly the application stop responding and the logs show a bunch of:

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 4) IJ031012: Unable to obtain lock in 60 seconds: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection

INFO  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener] IJ000302: Unregistered handle that was not registered: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk7.WrappedConnectionJDK7

WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] IJ000609: Attempt to return connection twice: org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener

WARN  [org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory] (default task-9) IJ030020: Detected queued threads during cleanup

ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-0) IJ031041: Connection handle has been closed and is unusable

ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1) IJ031050: The result set is closed
```

I think this is due to multiple access by different users (say 15, 20 users simultaneously), since with one/two users this not happens.

I'm on Hibernate 5.1 and Wildfly 10, and SQL Server 2014. It is a vanilla installation, with no tweaks or custom configurations. How can I fine-tune the infrastructure to avoid these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to the REST services being `@Stateless` and therefore opening transactions on each request. The solution was to inject `@Stateless` DAOs into the REST services: no more locking issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use HikariCP connection pool.
Based on your traffic configure no of connections in the connection pool as well as in database.
In the connection pool there is option to maintain some amount connections available all the time. And also set the connection isolation type as after commit only.

Below is the sample of it,

```
<persistence-unit name="sample" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>

            <!-- provider -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="com.xo.web.persistence.XOHikariCPConnectionProvider"/>

            <!-- Hibernate properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="hbm" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="show_sql"  value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode" value="after_transaction"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="2"/>
            <property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor" value="com.xo.web.persistence.intercept.XoEntityInterceptor"/>
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100"/>
            <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>


            <!-- Hikari settings -->
            <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="80" />
            <property name="autoCommit" value="false" />
            <property name="minimumPoolSize" value="20" />
            <property name="idleTimeout" value="60000" />
            <property name="maxLifetime" value="600000" />
            <property name="connectionInitSql" value="select 1" />
            <property name="connectionTimeout" value="1000" />
            <property name="validationTimeout" value="1000" />
            <property name="cachePrepStmts" value="true" />
            <property name="prepStmtCacheSize" value="250" />
            <property name="prepStmtCacheSqlLimit" value="2048" />

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Comment: Thank you! But it seems the connection pool not being the source of the problem. It is the `Unable to obtain lock in 60 seconds` which freezes some entities.